# Ошибка в Debian (version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found)

Tags: php, debian, ssh

Хочу создать сервер для игры. При запуске сервера пишет

```
root@a:/home/xooligan/test# ./start.sh
./bin/php7/bin/php: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /home/xooligan/test/bin/php7/bin/../lib/libleveldb.so.1)
```

Не подскажете как это исправить уже много чего пробывал. Не помогает((

Comment: A glib то собственно установлен ?

Comment: да установлен//

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44773296/libstdc-so-6-version-glibcxx-3-4-20-not-found

Comment: root@a:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu# strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_3.4.20
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
Нету версии которая мне нужна. Как ее установить?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46613765